# How can I time SQL-queries using psql?

Tags: postgresql, benchmark, psql

I would like to benchmark some SQL-queries agains my PostgreSQL database. Is there any way I can time SQL-queries using `psql`?

Comment: For more details on benchmarking PostgreSQL queries: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42012/9622

Answer (score 479, accepted):

Just turn on timing by entering:

`\timing`

Comment: From out bash, the "-c" option of `psql` does not allow this setting. You can do this with something like:

```psql  --o /dev/null <<EOF 

\timing

select 1

EOF
```

Comment: Or do `psql -c '\timing' -c 'select 1'`

Comment: Add `\timing` to `~/.psqlrc` if you want it enabled each time you start the client.

Comment: To enable timing for all your `psql` sessions, run this in your shell (note the double backslash): `echo '\\timing on' >> ~/.psqlrc`

Answer (score 80):

Timing can be turned on with `\timing` at the psql prompt (as Caleb already said).

If you are on 8.4 or above, [you can add an optional on/off argument to `\timing`](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/06/11/waiting-for-84-waiting-onoff/), which can be helpful if you want to be able to [set timing on in .psqlrc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156016/1396) - you can then set `\timing on` explicitly in a script where plain `\timing` would otherwise toggle it off

Answer (score 35):

The time that `\timing` returns also includes the network latency, if you're connecting to a remote server.

When you don't want that and don't need the query output too, better use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html),  which outputs the query plan with the planner estimates plus the actual execution times.

for example, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT foo from bar ;`

Comment: ... the only issue being that you don't receive the normal query output.

Comment: Using `explain analyze` yields times that are approximately double what I see when using `\timing`, which is the opposite of what I would expect based on the comments here regarding network latency. I suspect that there is overhead in the normal execution of `analyze` that adds to the query time. Based on the docs, I think that `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT foo FROM bar` will give you more useful timing information. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-explain.html for details.