# How can I time SQL-queries using psql from command line?

Tags: postgresql, performance, psql, query-performance

There is already a question "[How can I time SQL-queries using psql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/how-can-i-time-sql-queries-using-psql)" but I am missing answer how to do that from command line. How to run script with (optional) timing from command line – without `\timing [on|off]` in the script, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the shell command `time`

```sh
postgres@db:$ time psql db -c 'SELECT 1'
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)


real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Or, to combine a meta command with an SQL command, you could pipe a string to psql:

```sh
postgres@db:~/script$ echo '\timing \\ SELECT 1;' | LANG=C psql
Timing is on.
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

Time: 0.000 ms
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

> The special sequence `\\` (two backslashes) marks the end of arguments
> and continues parsing SQL commands, if any. That way SQL and psql
> commands can be freely mixed on a line. But in any case, the arguments
> of a meta-command cannot continue beyond the end of the line.

More options:

- [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860)

Comment: The `time` command would measure whole script not each query. Inspired by the second suggestion: `{ echo '\timing on;'; cat file.sql  } |psql`.