# Real time much greater than `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`'s execution time (index scan)

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I want to fetch up to 100 rows based on their id. The id is the primary key of the table.

The query that I had written looks like this:

```
select * from table where id = any ($1);
```

where `$1` is interpolated as an array of ids.

When using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I get the following plan ([explain link](https://explain.depesz.com/s/tDBJ)):

```
                                                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..44.98 rows=17 width=553) (actual time=100.048..834.209 rows=17 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using instagram_id_index_1000 on profiles_1000  (cost=0.43..44.98 rows=17 width=553) (actual time=100.046..834.163 rows=17 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{34491540,28977916,33241270,33609141,31043380,29364420,30247037,33311491,36267571,32886281,32366574,32569254,33038689,31089076,29416100,30455309,31570597}'::integer[]))
 Planning time: 424.512 ms
 Execution time: 834.280 ms
(5 rows)
```

When I actually execute it (with `\timing`) I get results in the 2-5 seconds range! I really cannot wrap my mind around such abysmal performance. The execution time provided by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` was already high in the first place.

Some context:
1) the database is local, so there is no network latency
2) the table I'm querying on is a materialized view
3) I also tried the `where id in (...)` variation and nothing changed
4) I tried to programmatically loop over the ids and run a separate query for each and it produces better results (around 1.5s)

Is there something that can be done here? I cannot believe that Postgres' performance in my case is this bad. The server also has 8 cores, is it possible to parallelize this query as much as possible?

Comment: Have you tried [joining against the values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html)?

Comment: The only thing that would be included in `\timing` that's not in the server-generated query execution time would be serializing the results and deserializing in psql; are any of the column values very large, on the order of 100+kb?

Comment: @AdamKG Unfortunately not, the rows are very small. Here are the stats: https://gist.github.com/rubik/b197f85d8c5c84daf309d397562dbffe, I used the query from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row)

Comment: @LowlyDBA Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that approach

Comment: Run the query in a tight loop (using \watch 0.001, for example) and then use an OS tool such as "top" to see what is using the time, "psql" itself or the postgres backend it is attached to.

Answer (score 6):

Firs the displayed query plan says:

> Limit  (cost=0.43..44.98 rows=17 width=553) ...

Obviously you added a **`LIMIT`** clause to the query, which is not in the query you show. If you didn't do the same in you second test, you may already have your answer: The same query with `LIMIT` (and without `ORDER BY`) can stop as soon as enough rows are found and can be *much* faster. Can also lead to a different query plan to begin with.

#### In principle

[**`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) measures the **time spent by the Postgres process**. Measurement is taken **on the server**. It adds a bit of overhead as compared to just executing the SQL command alone. For very cheap commands, that overhead may be more than the query cost. Overhead also depends on used options to some degree. You can minimize overhead with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS OFF, TIMING OFF)`. (The `TIMING` option of `EXPLAIN` is in no way related to psql's `\timing`; used to toggle additional measurements per plan node.)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)

> The `ANALYZE` option causes the statement to be actually executed, not
>   only planned. Then actual run time statistics are added to the
>   display, including the total elapsed time expended within each plan
>   node (in milliseconds) and the total number of rows it actually returned.

[About the `TIMING` option:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)

> Include actual startup time and time spent in each node in the output.
>   The overhead of repeatedly reading the system clock can slow down the
>   query significantly on some systems, so it may be useful to set this
>   parameter to `FALSE` when only actual row counts, and not exact times,
>   are needed. Run time of the entire statement is always measured, even
>   when node-level timing is turned off with this option. This parameter
>   may only be used when `ANALYZE` is also enabled. It defaults to `TRUE`.

[**`\timing` in psql**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), on the other hand, measures the **time between sending the command and receiving results - including network latency**. Measurement is taken **on the client**. That can be many times the execution alone. Seems to be your case.

Due to the mentioned overhead above, the opposite might be observed in cases with low latency and minimal data volume sent over the wire (especially with psql executed on the same server): `\timing` can report *faster* times.

There is a third good option: use the **shell command `time`** (also measuring on the client, obviously). See:

- [How can I time SQL-queries using psql from command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73270/how-can-i-time-sql-queries-using-psql-from-command-line)

#### Asides:

> When I actually execute it (with `\timing`)  ...

You are aware that `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does actually execute the given query, with all side effects - as opposed to just `EXPLAIN`.

> I tried to programmatically loop over the ids and run a separate query for each and it produces better results (around 1.5s)

A loop can produce query plans customized to each actual input value, based on statistics for the value. While a large `IN` or a large input array will produce a plan based on generic estimates. See:

- [How to use index for simple time range join?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254268/how-to-use-index-for-simple-time-range-join/254285#254285)

You can achieve similar effects as with your loop with a `LATERAL` join from a (derived) table or with many `SELECT` statements tied together with `UNION ALL` or with a loop in a (plpgsql) server-side function - without adding many times the network latency and/or planing overhead. Related:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539)
- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall reading something around this area recently, out of date statistics can cause a discrepancy between the estimated and actual execution plan activity, and there was another point made about table variables being interpreted as a single row rather than however many items the variable\array actually contains. Hope that helps.

Comment: In this case the actual and est rows are the same, though, so it doesn't seem like an issue with statistics.

Comment: good point Lowly