# How to set 'timing on' permanently in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, linux, configuration, psql, timing

I work with PostgreSQL in the command line interface. I would like to activate a **\timing** command permanently for every database in the cluster so every time I connect to a database - this parameter is on.
I searched in *postgresql.conf* file, but I haven't found anything like what I want to switch on.

My PostgreSQL is 9.5.4 on x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\timing` is specific to the client `psql`, not to the database server. You need to put that into the configuration file for `psql` which is `~/.psqlrc`

See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN100589

> psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide startup file (psqlrc) and then the user's personal startup file (~/.psqlrc), after connecting to the database but before accepting normal commands

Comment: It worked. I created a file:
touch ~/.psqlrc
and added '\timing' string there.

Comment: To enable timing for all your `psql` sessions, run this in your shell (note the double backslash): `echo '\\timing on' >> ~/.psqlrc`